# Problema com DepencyResolver ao usar o TestServer, diferença entre instanciar HttpConfiguration e não instanciar

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api-2, simple-injector

Possuo um filtro simples de autorização que para obter uma instância de um service eu requisito em `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver`.
Assim:

```
var service = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(UserService)) as UserService;
```

Rodando a aplicação Web API 2 para testar manualmente funciona, a instância é obtida.

Porém eu **não** estou instanciando diretamente o `HttpConfiguration` como a maioria dos exemplos na web, que são parecidos como esse:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    ...
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    ...
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

Ao invés disso estou usando um template que me foi entregue pelo VS onde a classe `Startup` está vazia, apenas com a anotação de `OwinStartup`, assim:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SampleAPI.WebApi.Startup))]
namespace SampleAPI.WebApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

E em minha `Global.asax.cs` tenho:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ValidatorOptions.LanguageManager.Culture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

Ou seja, funciona quando uso a instancia de `HttpConfiguration` que está em `GlobalConfiguration`.

Por conta de problemas para pegar a instância do serviço nesse filtro através do `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver` é que mudei para essa configuração.
E Mesmo antes setando o `container` do `SimpleInjector` no `HttpConfiguration` que instanciei, também não funcionava. Assim:

```
config.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

Então do jeito que configurei funciona! Até que no meu Teste de Integração usando o `TestServer` com os exemplos de configuração na Web não consigo obter a instância do serviço:

```
internal class OwinTestConf
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Já tentei também passando o `DependencyResolver` para essa instância de `HttpConfiguration`, mas não adiantou.

```
internal class OwinTestConf
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        config.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver();
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Qual a diferença entre instanciar diretamente o `HttpConfiguration` contra não instanciar diretamente, como em minha configuração, e porque não consegui obter as instâncias ao instanciar o HttpConfiguration como que pelo Teste de Integração com o TestServer eu também nao estou conseguindo?